Syncfusion ejs-grid child grid icon navigates away from page
I'm trying to add a child grid to a Syncfusion ejs-grid in Vue.
The problem I'm having is that the arrow that is added to the row to allow you to expand a row is causing navigation when I click it.
The arrow is an <a> element with href="#" but my app is using vue-router and the URL fragment is important. Clicking the arrow causes navigation to "#", which is the home page of my app.
Is there a way to stop the arrow from doing any navigation?

Turns out, the problem was with the provide. I had missed the square brackets from the line
provide('grid', [DetailRow]);

After correcting this line, there was no longer any navigation when clicking on the expansion arrows.
